# Is a "convivial item" a good way to describe an item that makes you happy or is there a better word?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am trying to come up with a name for a thread where you post items that make you happy

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about [***Naming,** including naming programming variables/classes*](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) something that doesn't (yet) exist and/or doesn't have an established name.

Comment: Post it on the cheerful thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could use "convivial" to describe an item that brings you happiness in the sense that it creates a cheerful, sociable atmosphere, it might not be the most common or intuitive way to describe an object that makes you happy. Convivial usually describe an atmosphere where food or drinking is involved. Better alternatives are: Joyful, uplifting, comforting, heartwarming, etc.

Etymology: The Latin word "convivium" means "a feast" or "a banquet," and is derived from "con-" meaning "together" and "vivere" meaning "to live." So "convivial" originally referred to an **atmosphere** or event that involved feasting, merrymaking, and enjoying the company of others.

The word "convivial" may have entered the English language in the early 17th century and has since been used to describe a variety of social situations and environments that are friendly, lively, and enjoyable.